# Create Wrapper class in apex - Variable Does Not Exists

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I'm new to salesforce.

getting `Variable does not exist: parguarList` Can anyone please help on this,

```
public with sharing  class GetParentGuardianController {

public List<ParentGuardian> parguarList = new List<ParentGuardian>();

@AuraEnabled (cacheable = true)
public static List<Enrollment__c> getParentGuardian(String EnrollmentId) {      

    system.debug('ENROL ' + EnrollmentId);      

    List<Enrollment__c> ls = [select  Id, Father_First_Name__c, Father_Last_Name__c, Father_Email__c, Father_Cell__c
                              ,Mother_First_Name__c ,Mother_Last_Name__c, Mother_Email__c, Mother_Cell__c
                              from Enrollment__c WHERE Name=:EnrollmentId];
    Map<Id, Enrollment__c> m = new Map<Id, Enrollment__c>(ls);

    list<Enrollment__c> obj = [Select Id, Father_First_Name__c, Father_Last_Name__c  from Enrollment__c WHERE Name=: 'E0008'];


        parguarList = new list<ParentGuardian>();
return ls;         
}

public class ParentGuardian{
    public String FirstName      {get;set;}
    public String LastName     {get;set;}
    public String Email   {get;set;}
    public String Phone   {get;set;}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Static methods cannot access member variables. This is your member variable  `public List<ParentGuardian> parguarList = new List<ParentGuardian>();`. You need to define that in the static method itself.

Comment: Declaring a static variable in the class in this case makes no sense at all. I'd just advise OP to instantiate the variable locally.

Comment: Hmm, agree. @rael_kid

Answer (score 0):

Apex does not support accessing Non-static variables from a static context.

**Solutions:**

- Marking the Method non-static should work

  public List getParentGuardian(String EnrollmentId)
- Instantiating the variable locally within the lexical scope of static method

  @AuraEnabled (cacheable = true)
  public static List getParentGuardian(String EnrollmentId) { 
    List parguarList = new List();
  }